# Two NIC same machine not able to ping

Tags: linux, networking, nic

I am facing an problem that is i have 2 nic in same machine named NIC-1 and NIC-2.
Both to them have static IP like 192.168.10.12 (NIC-1) and 172.16.10.12(NIC-2).
Both of them are on same machine and they are not connected by any wire.
I want to send packets between the two but the mail problem is i am not able to ping them.
Will the "brctrl" command help me in sending packets between them?

Comment: When an interface is not wired, it is marked as DOWN. Running `ifconfig` would show they are not `UP`. Running `ethtool` would show `Link=no`. Even with single NIC, when down, it can't be pinged.

Answer (score 0):

IPv4 addresses starting with 10.x.x.x, 172.x.x.x, and 192.168.x.x are [private IP addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network).  They are for private networks and not publicly routable.

To be able to ping between those two NICs, you would have to have IP addresses that are on the same subnet (they can be on the same private network), or that have routing masks that enable them to see each other on the net, and be connected via some physical medium.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things in your Problem :

1. Both network should be in same subnet to ping .
2. there should be some cable mechanism to transfer packets or use loopback address for particular NIC .